# Select rows with missing value in a Julia dataframe

Tags: dataframe, julia, subset

I'm just started exploring Julia and am struggeling with subsetting dataframes. I would like to select rows where `LABEL` has the value "B" and `VALUE` is missing. Selecting rows with "B" works fine, but trying to add a filter for missing fails. Any suggestions how to solve this. Tips for good documentation on subsetting/filtering dataframes in Julia are welcome. In the Julia documentation I haven't found a solution.

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(ID = 1:5, LABEL = ["A", "A", "B", "B", "B"], VALUE = ["A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", missing])
df[df[:LABEL] .== "B", :] # works fine
df[df[:LABEL] .== "B" && df[:VALUE] .== missing, :] # fails
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
filter([:LABEL, :VALUE] => (l, v) -> l == "B" && ismissing(v), df)
```

(a very similar example is given in the documentation of the `filter` function).

If you want to use `getindex` then write:

```
df[(df.LABEL .== "B") .& ismissing.(df.VALUE), :]
```

The fact that you need to use `.&` instead of `&&` when working with arrays is not DataFrames.jl specific - this is a common pattern in Julia in general when indexing arrays with booleans.